# In J2ME, how can I tell whether or not Daylight Saving Time is enabled?

Tags: date, java-me, dst

How can I get whether or not daylight saving time is switched on? (Because if it is on, the `Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY` is (for example) 11 instead of 12.) Or should I use another way to get the hour of day?

Comment: I think you should rewrite this question.

Comment: Unless you plan on converting between TimeZones, I'm not sure why you'd even need to know this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the [J2ME doc for TimeZone](http://java.sun.com/javame/reference/apis/jsr118/java/util/TimeZone.html).  You want to look at TimeZone.getOffeset() I believe, in order to accomplish what you have described.